# To show the code is not linear

Tags: number-theory, information-theory, coding-theory

Consider the projective plane of order 2 or the Fano plane and its incidence matrix.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane.
Any two rows of the incidence matrix thought of as binary words, have distance 4 from each other, since they have 3 ones,whose positions agree exactl once.
If we denote these rows by $r_1,r_2,...,r_7$ then $d(r_i,r_j)=4$.
Now consider the complements $s_1,...,s_7$ of the rows, where $s_i$ is obtained from $r_i$ by interchanging $0's$ and $1's$.
So, $d(s_i,s_j)=4$ and $d(r_i,s_j)=3$. So the code $C={(0,1,r_1,...,r_7,s_1,...,s_7)}$ is a (7,16,3) code. We need to show that this code is non linear.
Now I know what linear code is. but I am unable to that it is not a subspace of $F_2^7$. I was thinking that if I get a generator matrix and then taking two rows $r_1,r_2$ I will show the non-linearity. But I don't know how to get the generator matrix or if I am wrong please correct me, I know the structure of a generator matrix for linear code.So,please tell me how to show the non-linearity of that code?

Comment: Check the exercise, please. Unless I misunderstood the construction the resulting code most emphatically IS linear. It is possibly the most famous linear code in existence, the single-error-correcting Hamming code of length seven.

Comment: The weight three words in the Fano plane come from 2-dimensional subspaces of the 3-space sans the origin. The complements of those are the cosets of those 2-spaces. Together with the all zeros word and the all ones word you get exactly the linear code defined by the parity check matrix
$$H=\pmatrix{1&0&1&0&1&0&1\cr0&1&1&0&0&1&1\cr 0&0&0&1&1&1&1\cr}.$$

Comment: Yeah, I have checked. The exercise is in the book Coding and Information theory by Steven Roman. The question is there and correct.

Comment: We need to show that the code is not linear, but I checked that every linear combination of the elements is there, but which point I am missing I don't know.

Comment: Then it looks like the exercise is simply wrong.

Comment: Now I am also thinking so.